# Can't access data returning from ajax in json format

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, get

This is a dropdown list in my code

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drp1">
<asp:listItem value="value1">
<asp:listItem value="value2">
<asp:listItem value="value3">
<asp:listItem value="value4">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I used this code in jquery

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp1").change(function () {
var link = "https://api.something/?convert=" + $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp1 option:selected").text();
$.ajax({
type:"GET", 
url: link, 
success: function(response) {
alert("succcess");
$("body").append(JSON.stringify(response));
}, 
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus);
},
dataType: "jsonp"
})
});
```

The data returned (as seen in developer's tool, yes a response is received) looks like this

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key4": "1", 
        "key5": "8082.11", 
        "key6": "1.0"
    }
]
```

and yet ajax success block does not run am I doing something wrong? Please help. Also how do I access value at index 4.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Specifically something mentioning CORS or 'No Access Control header was present..'?

Comment: no such error appears in the console, the weird thing is i can actually see that my required result has been received in sources in dev tools

Comment: If this is the complete response than that's not JSONP (`dataType: "jsonp"`)

Comment: and you didn't get the `success` alert ?

Comment: I changed the dataType to "json" and it does give NO Access Control now. Is there any particular reason that response is received when it's jsonp and No access when using json

Comment: The response may have reached your browser but it never made the last steps into your script. First because the API doesn't support JSONP and second because it doesn't like CORS.

Comment: that's true. can you suggest a solution or alternate method

Comment: Just search for CORS related questions, that's a common problem on SO. A tl;dr: If you cannot change the API you will need a server.